# Escolher um índice de uma lista

Tags: python, lista, random

Tenho uma lista:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Gostaria de escolher um valor entre os índices 6 e 14 dessa lista, mas fazer isso 5 vezes e armazenar esses valores em outra lista. Como faço?

Se fosse de qualquer índice, seria:

```
random.choose(l)
```

Mas não é isso que quero. Podem auxiliar-me por favor?

Comment: na verdade `l` é uma lista de listas, algo como: `l = [lista1, lista2, lista3, lista4, ..., lista15]` e `lista1 = [1, 2, 3], lista2 = [4, 5, 6], etc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agora não consigo testar mas creio que pode fazer:

```
index1 = 6
index2 = 14
vals = []

for i in range(0, 5):
    # l[index1:index2] = lista dos valores entre index1 e index2
    vals.append(random.choice(l[index1:index2])) # aqui armazena os valores
```

Para não armazenar repetidos em vez do ciclo `for` faça:

```
while len(vals) < 5:
    randVal = random.choice(l[index1:index2])
    if randVal not in vals:
        vals.append(randVal)
```

Cuidado que desta maneira tem de garantir que existem mais de 5 (ou 5) valores entre index1 e index2, senão entra em ciclo infinito.

Comment: joia amigo @Miguel, irei testar! onde estou agora só consigo comunicar por aqui haha

Comment: tem como eu escolher no lugar de um valor do índice, escolher o próprio índice? Fiz aqui e funcionou, mas ele não percorre pelo índice, mas pelo valor de cada item em cada indice.

Answer (score 0):

É só passar um subconjunto da lista para o random.choice:

```
random.choice(l[6:14])
```